# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=class java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, rest, jersey

do I need a rest to answer files and download them with a method get or some other http method, but I've got this error which I will describe below:

```
GRAVE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=class java.util.HashMap.
```

This is a class example which gives me the same error, download any pdf file but I have the same error with this.

```
@GET
@Path("/pdf")
public Response downloadPdfFile() {
    StreamingOutput fileStream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            System.out.println("ENTRANDO!!!!");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_PATH));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
        }
    };
    return Response
            .ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = myfile.pdf")
            .build();
}
```

with these units that are used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**
I found that  org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature in jersey configuration causes the error but i can't remove this feature but i upload multipart files 
please help

Comment: Try adding @Produces(MediaType. APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) on top of the API signature

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code you are showing. Please show either the real code or the real error.

Comment: The produces produce The same error , and i know i dont user hashmap but WebLogic return this error 

Comment: i detect that  org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature in jersey configuration causaes the error any idea???